# GAE printing same log statement multiple times

Tags: google-app-engine

In the GAE logger i could see that same log statement is printing multiple times. How do i control the logger to print the log statement only once?
I am using Log4j for my logging.Do i need to do anything in the logger.properties to control the duplicate log statements?
Also i am not sure how to silence the apache http, client, socketcontrol, headers logs in the logging, there are so many logs related to apache http, which is making it difficult to find the relevant logs.

Comment: I have never seen duplicate statements. Are you sure this is not your code being executed multiple times, e.g. retries on fails, etc.? Do these statements have an identical timestamp?

Comment: Yes this is not my code. I see identical timestamps for all these timestamps.

Comment: Did you try various options in the Logging tool in the console?